# MySQL query not inserting row

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I have a form in my handler:

```
<form action="../submitcomment.php" method="post">
                <input maxlength=100 size=60 type="text" name="IP" value="' . $ip . '" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden">
                <input maxlength=100 size=60 type="text" name="BlogId" value="' . $blogId . '" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden">
                <input maxlength=100 size=60 type="text" name="Date" value="' . $date . '" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden">         
                <input maxlength=100 size=60 type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
                <input maxlength=100 size=60 type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
                <input maxlength=100 size=60 type="text" name="Comment" placeholder="Enter Your Comment">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Your Comment">
                </form>
```

The action is `submitcomment.php`:

```
$ip = $_POST['IP'];
$BlogId = $_POST['BlogId'];
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Comment = $_POST['Comment'];

$blog = new Blogs();

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{
    $addComment = $blog->insertComment($ip, $BlogId, $Date, $Name, $Email, $Comment);
    header('Location: http://www.ryan.archi.dev.netsite.co.uk/Blog?success=1');
}else{
    header('Location: http://www.ryan.archi.dev.netsite.co.uk/Blog?fail=1');
}
```

which reference a function in my class:

```
function insertComment($ip, $BlogId, $Date, $Name, $Email, $Comment)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO BlogComments (Name, Comment, IPAddress, Email, BlogId, Date) VALUES ('$Name', '$Comment', '$ip', '$Email', '$BlogId', '$Date')";
        $oDatabase = new database;
        $connection = $oDatabase->Connect();
        $result = mysql_query ($query, $connection);
        return $result;
    }
```

The attempt to insert does not return or raise any errors.
As far as I'm aware this should be working, Can you spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Uff, let SQL Injection live long!

Comment: Are there any errors returned by `mysql_query`?

Comment: Does the attempt to insert return or raise any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with the column named `Date` - `date` is a reserved word (I guess of all known RDBMS).

You have to escape this word in Your query:

```
INSERT INTO BlogComments (Name, Comment, IPAddress, Email, BlogId, `Date`) VALUES ('$Name', '$Comment', '$ip', '$Email', '$BlogId', '$Date')
```

Also Your code gives anybody a chance to do a SQL injection attack therefore You should at least escape any user input or better use MySQLi or PDO.

You can do the escaping by php function http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string :

```
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['IP']);
$BlogId = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BlogId']);
$Date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Date']);
$Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']);
$Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
$Comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Comment']);
```

Comment: When i done the `mysqld_real_escape_string` it throws this error: `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) `

Comment: So You are not connected to the DB. Where and when are You connecting to DB? Edit Your question and add the code of connecting to DB.

Comment: I connect to the db in my class function not in the submit comment where them variables are defined

Comment: So when You call `$blog = new Blogs;` You are only connecting to DB? Then just move this line **before** the `mysql_real_escape_string` calls are done.

Comment: that wont work because im only connecting to the databse via a function from that class, read code in question

Comment: Ahh, didn't see - but that is not very good approach. You should connect to a DB in some bootstrap to be connected for all the time the code is being executed. Call Your `$oDatabase = new database; $connection = $oDatabase->Connect();` at the beginning of submit and You are done. You also should write the `Database` class as a singleton thus calling only its static `getInstance()` method that will either create and return an instance or only return the existing instance of this object...

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug it? Is the connection to the database established successfully? You did no mysql escaping maybe the insert query fails.